# Is LaTeX used for creating road signs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

For example, consider British traffic signs, as seen in [this page](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/traffic-signs). I put some examples below. They have the TeX feeling, don't you think? I guess I could probably reproduce them using TikZ/Pgfplot.

**Do you think they are compiled with LaTeX? Maybe in your particular country?** Examples would be great.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't doubt that it is possible to achieve this with TikZ but I doubt that the 'designers' and the traffic sign manufactures use LaTeX for this

Comment: Why? What software do you think they use? This might be outsourced to graphic design companies, which could perfectly use Latex. It's free, and extremely powerful.

Comment: this would require a certain amount of time travel, so it's unlikely I think.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Locally, some of our road signs are hand-drawn by children. Maybe we could offer them a 'Ducks crossing' sign?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least for the UK, the answer is a clear **no**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_signs_in_the_United_Kingdom#History):

> Road signs in the United Kingdom are governed by an extremely complex and detailed set of guidelines... Traffic signs are generally designed using specialist computer software. The two most popular systems are [SignPlot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignPlot) from Buchanan Computing, and KeySign (previously AutoSign) from Key Traffic Systems, originally developed in the 1980s by Pete Harman and Geoff Walker whilst working for Humberside County Council.

The Wikipedia page on SignPlot adds:

> The degree of inbuilt guidance and intelligence has increased over that time to the extent that it now automates almost all the layout and spacing rules of the Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions, Traffic Signs Manual Chapter 7, and drawings issued by the Welsh Assembly Government for bilingual signing.

Most countries are likely to have similarly detailed regulations for the layout of road signs. Encoding such a body of rules into, say, a TikZ library is likely to be a non-trivial task.

Comment: I think I will offer the UK government a deal, so that for a 1/100th of the cost I can create their road signs... Anyone interested in a partnership? It could be called Roadz, or Traffikz.

Comment: @luchonacho see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_road_network_size   now you're  working for me ;-)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the joke :(

Comment: @luchonacho  i just mean that UK is in 19th place so (IMHO) it's  not a very good example.

Comment: @luchonacho And you'd need two bilingual versions just for Wales. And the size of our road network ranks where exactly?!

Comment: @touhami ^^^^^ (Don't know if Gaelic versions are required, but probably not.)

Comment: @cfr We've got [dialect versions of road signs](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/norfolk/7593678.stm)  in Norfolk ;-)

Comment: @luchonacho I'd read up on the exact requirements of designing road signs before venturing into that territory. Not that it'd be likely, considering the design is not terribly likely to be a significant cost factor compared to manufacturing, placing and maintaining these things.

Comment: @Cubic Especially since they don't exactly need to come up with new designs very much, but only if there's a need for a new kind of sign, I guess.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot We have road signs here designed by local primary school children for the same purpose. (Not dialect - usually just bilingual - but aimed at reducing speeding in areas where children play or near schools.)